# How to make webservice in JSON in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, web-services

Please find the below code for webservice. It is the post method webservice but when I am trying to parse it from iPhone. It is throwing error.

```
function TestMe(strURI) {
            //alert(strURI);

            $.ajax({
                url: strURI,
                type: 'POST',
                //contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "Input": [
                        {
                            "MeetingId":"2",
                            "FromUserId":"1",
                            "DBMessage": "Test Message by index page"
                        }]                        
                }),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('success');
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('error');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    //alert('complete');
                }
            });
        }
```

In other class I have defined this method

```
public string SaveDiscussionBoardMsg(Stream input)
        {
            string body = new StreamReader(input).ReadToEnd();
            string strJSONResult = "";
            objDAMeeting = new DA.Meeting();
            BO.BMO.DiscussionBoard objBODiscussionBoard = new BO.BMO.DiscussionBoard();

            //Method-2
            //string JsonInsertSQL = @" {""Input"":[{""MeetingId"":1,""DBMessage"":""My Msg"",""FromUserId"":1},{""MeetingId"":1,""DBMessage"":""My Msg"",""FromUserId"":1}]}";
            //string JsonInsertSQL = @" {""Input"":[{""MeetingId"":1,""DBMessage"":""My Msg"",""FromUserId"":1}]}";
            dynamic dynObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
            foreach (var item in dynObj.Input)
            {
                objBODiscussionBoard.MeetingId = Convert.ToInt32(item.MeetingId.ToString());
                objBODiscussionBoard.DBMessage = item.DBMessage.ToString();
                objBODiscussionBoard.FromUserId = Convert.ToInt32(item.FromUserId.ToString());

                strJSONResult = objDAMeeting.SaveDiscussionBoardMsg(objBODiscussionBoard);
            }

            strJSONResult = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", strPrefix, "\"" + strJSONResult + "\"", strPostfix);
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strJSONResult);

            objDAMeeting = null;

            return strJSONResult;
        }
```

We are using WCF

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "/SaveDiscussionBoardMsg")]
        string SaveDiscussionBoardMsg(Stream input);
```

I am getting this error. Please find below error.

```
{
    html =     {
        body =         {
            div =             {
                "div#@Attributes@#" =                 {
                    id = content;
                };
                p =                 (
                    "Request Error",
                                        {
                        a = "service help page";
                        "p#@Attributes@#" =                         {
                            xmlns = "";
                        };
                    }
                );
            };
        };
        head =         {
            style = "BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}";
            title = "Request Error";
        };
        "html#@Attributes@#" =         {
            xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: what error it is throwing?

Comment: Debug the web service. Is it returning the Json? If it is, the problem is client side.

Comment: Enable the debugger on the phone and see if that gives you any more info....http://browsers.about.com/od/allaboutwebbrowsers/ss/iphonedebugger.htm

Comment: I have added the error which i am getting. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am calling the webservice in iPhone app. It is not responsive website.

Comment: please do not use WCF REST ! it's deprecated. Move to asp.net Web Api !

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic - When did MS deprecate WCF REST?  I agree that WebAPI is probably better in this case, but I'm not aware of any official announcement that WCF REST has been done away with from MS.

Comment: @Tim you're probably true ... but starting a new project with WCF REST is not pertinent today, especially for mobile. WCF REST tries to put REST concepts in WCF which was designed  for SOAP. It's not dead and you can still create WCF REST Service, like LinqToSql classes ... The community around this tech is constantly decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding dataType: 'json' as

```
   $.ajax({
            url: strURI,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            //contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "Input": [
                    {
                        "MeetingId":"2",
                        "FromUserId":"1",
                        "DBMessage": "Test Message by index page"
                    }]                        
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('error');
            },
            complete: function () {
                //alert('complete');
            }
        });
```